# AutoIt Clicking a onClick Javascript button with no name or id only class in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, autoit

Trying to script a button click on a button on the amazon website that looks like this:

```
  <span class="action-go" onclick="MYO.JS.handle_action($(this).parent().find('.action option:selected').attr('value'),&#10;     $(this).parent().find('.action option:selected').attr('url'));">
          <input width="21" height="21" align="absmiddle" type="image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/abis-ui/buttons/go._V187564664_.gif" border="0">
        </span>

<input width="21" height="21" align="absmiddle" type="image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/abis-ui/buttons/go._V187564664_.gif" border="0">
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Func GetButtons()
    Local $oBtns = _IETagNameGetCollection($g_oIE, "span")
    For $oBtn In $oBtns
        If String($oBtn.classname) = "action-go" Then
            _IEAction($oBtn, "click")
        EndIf
        ExitLoop
Next
EndFunc
```

**Solution that Worked**

```
Func ClickButton()
$HWND = _IEPropertyGet($g_oIE, 'HWnd')
WinSetState($HWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
_IEAction($g_oIE,"visible")
_IELoadWait($g_oIE)
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 290, 354, 2)
EndFunc   ;==>GetButtons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time to script you a solution, but i can tell you how I would do it. The trick is to not click on the button, but its position.
This only works if the GUI allways has the same proportionalities.

1. You detect the position of the window. As long as it has a name this should work.
2. You detect the position of the button relative to the window, by useing AutoIt Window Info.
3. You add both values and click on that position.

You can click on a position by useing [MouseClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm).

Comment: That worked! But I see an issue, as you mentioned, if I switch desktops with a different then the code won't work correctly because the window size will be different.

Comment: There are shortcuts called  (AT)DesktopWidth and (AT)DesktopHeight. With those you can calculate the positions, even with different screen resolutions. Glad I could help.